# Selenium: how to automate Range sliders

Tags: java, jquery, html, selenium, slider

I want to automate the [Range Slider](http://rangeslider.js.org/) based on the given parameter values. I just tried with `Actions class` but facing the problem in calculation of moving xOffset value.

Code what i have tested.

```java
void automateApplication( RemoteWebDriver driver ) {
    driver.get( "http://rangeslider.js.org/" );
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //Thread.sleep( 1000 * 60 * 1 );

    rangeSlidePointer("//div[@id='js-rangeslider-0']/div[2]", 147, 0);

    System.out.println("Enter something in console to quit the browser and driver.");
    try {
        System.in.read();
        System.in.read();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
void rangeSlidePointer( String locator, int xOffset, int yOffset ) {
    WebDriverWait explicitWait = new WebDriverWait( driver, 1000 * 60 * 2 );
    By findBy = By.xpath( locator );
    WebElement sliderElement = explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable( findBy ));
    Actions moveSlider = new Actions(driver);
    Action action = moveSlider.dragAndDropBy(sliderElement, xOffset, yOffset).release().build();
    // Actions action = moveSlider.moveToElement(sliderElement).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(xOffset,yOffset).release();
    action.perform();
}
```

Observed form the Ranged slider application.

```html
<section id="top">
    <input type="range" min="10" max="1000" step="10" value="300" data-rangeslider="" 
        style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0;">
    <div class="rangeslider rangeslider--horizontal" id="js-rangeslider-0">
        <div class="rangeslider__fill" style="width: 529.495px;"></div>
        <div class="rangeslider__handle" style="left: 509.495px;"></div>
    </div>
    <output id="js-output">980</output>
</section>
```

```js
var elem = $x("//div[@id='js-rangeslider-0']")[0];
var offset = elem.offsetLeft - elem.offsetParent.offsetLeft;
console.dir( offset );

var elem = $(".rangeslider__handle");
var offset = elem.offset().left - elem.parent().offset().left;
console.dir( offset );
/*
tagName|nodeName = "DIV"
    clientWidth, offsetWidth, scrollWidth = 560
    clientHeight, offsetHeight, scrollHeight = 30

firstChild clientWidth = 419
           clientHeight = 20

lastChild clientWidth = 40
          clientHeight = 40

type="range" min="10" max="1000" step="10" value="300"
update=760
*/
```

For more information see this image:

[image]

I need an answer with respect to `XPath` or using `Actions Class` so that i can automate the following URLs:

Reference URL's

> https://www.hdfcbank.com/personal/personal-loan-emi-calculator
>   https://www.icicibank.com/calculators/home-loan-emi-calculator.html
>   https://www.kotak.com/en/calculators/personal-loan-emi-calculator.html

as @Murthi suggested i can automate `http://rangeslider.js.org/` by changing the value of input field, using the below code.

```html
var ele = $('input[type="range"]');
ele.val(50).change();
```

But i did't want to change the value of input field, just need to change the slider based on its handle `rangeslider__handle` or `rangeslider rangeslider--horizontal`.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with action class and java script executor. But java script executor is working with 100% accuracy. But action class is not 100% accuracy. Find the below code for details. Better, you can use java script.

```
    @Test
    public void testSlider(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Projects\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("http://rangeslider.js.org/");

        //To slide using action class
        slide(driver, 500);

        //To slide using jQuery
        slideUsingJQuery(driver, 100);


    }

  public void slide(WebDriver driver, int value){

        WebElement slider=driver.findElement(By.id("js-rangeslider-0"));
        WebElement sliderHandle=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#top .rangeslider__handle"));
        int width=slider.getSize().getWidth();
        int x=(int)Float.parseFloat(sliderHandle.getCssValue("left").replace("px", ""));
        System.out.println(width);
        float min=10;
        float max=1000;
        float offsetX=width/(max-min)*value;
        System.out.println(offsetX);

        new Actions(driver).dragAndDropBy(sliderHandle, -x, 10).dragAndDropBy(sliderHandle, (int)offsetX, 10).perform();

    }

    public void slideUsingJQuery(WebDriver driver, int value){
        WebElement slider=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='range']"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$(arguments[0]).val("+value+").change()", slider);

    }
```

Comment: can you provide only `jquery` code so that i can try in my browser console.

Comment: $('input[type="range"]').val(50).change();

Comment: can you provide information related to `xpath`. like $x('xpath')

`var ele = $x('//div[@id="js-rangeslider-0"]/div[2]')[0];
console.dir(ele);`

Comment: I am not able to getting you.

Comment: i just want the answer either using pure `xpath` or by using `Actions class`, So that i can automate all the related `loan-emi-calculator` URL's

Comment: pure Xpath means related to slider handle or its parent div eg: `rangeslider__handle` or `rangeslider rangeslider--horizontal`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I can think of is getting the size and location from both the slider and the handle and use these to determine your range of motion.

The width of the slider div is `560 px`, the width of the handle div is `40 px` so your total range of motion is `520 px`.

If you get the position from the slider element you get something like:

```
x: 176
y: 462
```

If you get the position from the handle element you get something like:

```
x: 334
y: 452
```

In this case you can move the handle element `520 px` starting from `176 px` up to `696 px` (176 + 520). When `x = 334`, you can move the handle `158 px` to the left or `362 px` to the right.

Comment: for a given amount i need to calculate the current handle position, form their i need to provide xOffset `+ve` or `-ve` value. The total monitoring range is 560 - 40/2 = 540.

Comment: The handle cannot go out of the slider, so handle always takes up 40px of space, so: 560 - 40 = 520

Comment: When I look at the first slide, I can retrieve the handle by using 
`let handle = document.querySelector('#js-rangeslider-0 > div.rangeslider__handle');`.

When the handle is completely to the left, calling `handle.offsetLeft` returns 0. When it is completely to the right, it returns 520

Comment: k, iam also getting the same. can you automate the slider based on the given values, where i am facing the problem.